# Python coding practice : Return None vs Return same datatype with empty value?

Tags: python

Shall same datatypes be used to return from functions, or assign default values ? or None ? What is a better coding practice, and why ?

eg. Some pseudo  codes in python :

/1

```
def my_position():   # returns a positive integer if found
    if(object is present):
          position = get_position()
          return position # eg 2,3,4,6
    else: 
          return None     # or return -1 or 0 ??
```

/2

```
def get_database_rows():    
    do query to whatever database
    if(rows are found):
       return [list of rows]
    else:
       return None  # or return empty list []  ?
```

/3

```
the_dictionary = {'a' : 'john','b':'mike','c': 'robert' }  # values are names i.e. non empty string
my_new_var = the_dictionary.get('z', None)  # or the_dictionary.get('z','')  ?
```

Comment: Depends on what you're going to do with the value you get.

Comment: @larsmans usually there are ways to deal with empty cases, `is not None` or otherwise `len(datalist) > 0` , `position > 0` etc . This again gives rise to the question, compare with None, or compare with empty value ?

Comment: When in doubt, raise an exception. That's the most explicit way of indicating failure. But, when you're doing something like collecting a list of items that satisfy a criterion (your #2) and none of your items satisfy it, then by all means, return an empty list.

Comment: @DhruvPathak, or just us `if retval:`, which will fail for `Falsey` values (`False`, 0, [], {}, (), etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Raise an `IndexError` if the item is not found. This is what Python's `list` does. (Or maybe return the index where the item should have lived when doing a binary search or similar operation.)
2. Think about what your function does, logically: if it returns a list of all items in a DB that satisfy some criterion, and there are no such items, then it makes sense to return an empty list since that allows all the usual list operations (`len`, `in`) to function without the need for an explicit check.

   However, if the absence of the required items indicates inconsistency, then raise an exception.
3. My previous remark applies especially to this case: *it depends* on what you're going to do with the value you get. An ordinary `dict` just raises a `KeyError` when a key is not found. You're replacing that exception with a value, so you should know which value makes sense in the context of your program. If no value does, then just let the exception fly.

That said, returning `None` is often a bad idea because it may obscure bugs. `None` is the default return value in Python, so a function returning it may indicate nothing more than its author's forgetting a `return` statement:

```
def food(what):
    if what == HAM:
        return "HAM!"
    if what == SPAM:
        return " ".join(["SPAM" for i in range(10)])
    # should raise an exception here

lunch = food(EGGS)    # now lunch is None, but what does that mean?
```

Comment: Yeah, as usual, it depends is the best answer. I'd add dict.get that dict.setdefault behavior can also be a very good alternative in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1**: Raise IndexError.

Rationale: returning -1 is C-style, while raising `IndexError` is more pythonic.

**Case 2**: Return empty list.

Rationale: avoid unnecessary null checks. Also refer to the book "Effective Java(2ed) Item43 *Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls*"(Yes, it's Java, but the arguments are still valid)

**Case 3**: Depends.

Rationale: if you don't want to raise `KeyError`, whether empty string or `None` depends on actual needs, but be careful of two things: first, be consistent, don't mixed `None` and empty string interchangeably; second, make sure empty strings are distinguishable from valid values(i.e. valid values cannot be empty), if that's in doubt, use `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option not listed in the question: throwing an exception. It seems to be popular enough in python, and it's sometimes better to follow a common practice for your language than to look for an abstractly *best* solution.

As of your examples:

1. I would consider `-1` because that's what `"".find` does, or throwing a `ValueError` because that's what `[].index` does (I don't mean the first option is the best one). I would never use one-based indices, so the value `0` is a valid result and can't be used to represent emptyness.
2. I would prefer an empty list because the caller is not guaranteed to be interested in *emptyness* as a special case. If I want to count all rows for several queries, I'd hate to handle `None` specially. If there is a logically distinct situation where the list of rows *cannot be produced* (as opposed to *there are no matching rows*), I would consider using `None` or throwing an exception for this case.
3. The meaning of an example is unclear, especially given that `None` is a valid dictionary key. But if I *had* to use some special value where string is normally expected, I would prefer it to be `None` (and if you prefer an empty string, it's important to know for sure that you never need a *valid empty string*, representing nothing special but itself).

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are generally preferred, but if you don't want to use them, it really depends on what you want.

When asking for a non-existant item's index in a list returning `None` is probably as good as returning `-1` because, well, there is no possible good answer to that query. After calling that function, I *have* to check whether it could produce a result or not before proceeding with the result.

Bu when asking the list of all odd numbers in a list, you should return `[]` rather than `None` because `[]` is a perfectly valid answer. I might want to know how many odd numbers I have in the original list, and 0 is the answer I need if it is empty, so something like

```
len(odd_numbers(lst))
```

should always work. Returning `None` in that situation would be tricky and error-prone as I would have to do

```
0 if odd_numbers(lst) is None else len(odd_numvers(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think empty list is better, but I don't think there is a "general" answer to this question: it often depends on situation. One thing to definitely avoid — retuern more then ine type of value (except of None). I've seen code, where function coulr return: string, None, bool, 1, 2 and 3. That was a menace.

Answer (score 0):

These cases are different.

1 - `return position # eg 2,3,4,6`

This is like a record, so `None` makes sense to me. (Or, as others have mentioned, if you always expect to have a position then raise an exception.)

2 - `return [list of rows]`

This is a list of rows so returning `[]` is logical and you will not have to special case iterating the result, you can just use `for row in rows:`.

3 - `the_dictionary = {'a' : 'john','b':'mike','c': 'robert' }

Again this looks like a record, so missing value would naturally be `None` (usually). (And if you *always* expect to have a dictionary, then raise an exception).